# Ideas for a more compact for loop?

Tags: language-design

A for loop is quite an important part of a programming language so you don't want to spend a lot of time typing it out every time for prototyping. An example of a quite ugly syntax is:

```
for(int x=0;x<100;x++){
```

I would like to come up with some ideas for a simpler syntax for a new programming fast prototyping language. One idea I had was:

```
(0..99):x=>{
```

So you would write:

```
(0..99):x=>{
     print(x);
}
```

Or another way might be:

```
x=>{
     print(x);
}(0..99)
```

But that is not so good as the limits are at the end so might not be so readable.

Maybe another might be in a more python-esque syntax:

```
x=0..99:
   print x
```

About a third less characters than the javascript example. Any better ideas? The less characters the better. I guess the minimum possible would be:

```
x 0 99
   print x
```

Then to do a times table:

```
x 1 10
  y 1 10
    print x*y " "
  newl
```

I suppose one could also shorten if statements. Instead of `if(x<3){` one could just write:

```
x<3
```

So

```
int x=3;
int y="Hello";
for(int z=0;z<10;z++){
    if(z+x<5){
       print(y)
    }
}
```

would become:

```
x 3
y "Hello"
z 0 9
  z+x<5
    print y
```

(half the number of characters)

One could imagine function definition. Instead of `int f(int x, int y){ return x*y;}` one could have:

```
f x y->z
   z x*y
```

Probably a lot more unnecessary syntax one could take out. Such as a class maybe in the same way as javascript:

```
complex a b \
  x a
  y b
  add a b->c
     c comp a.x+b.x a.y+b.y
  mult a b->c
     c comp a.x*b.x-a.y*b.x a.x*b.y+a.y*b.x
```

Comment: There's a lot of programming language that doesn't have a `for loop` based "looping"

Comment: How do I specify a custom step for the loop? Like in Python `range(start, end, step)` or in C `for(int x = stat;x < end; x += step)`

Comment: If the new language will ever be used by other devs but you, then pick one and test. Change if you dislike how it works. However, if you want your language to be used by other devs, then run away from `The fewer characters the better`, because the code still has to be read more times it's written.

Comment: See APL (e.g. `{ ⍵ ∘.× ⍵ } ⍳ 10`) and https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ for existing terse languages

Answer (score 9):

> A for loop is quite an important part of a programming language

No? For-each loops are arguably an important part of a programming language, but traditional for loops are a smell in everything but the most foundational code.

> so you don't want to spend a lot of time typing it out every time for prototyping.

Typing code is a minuscule part of software creation. For loops are a minuscule part of programs.

You are optimizing the wrong thing.

Comment: I'm just talking about prototyping. Like outputting a times 3 times table.

Comment: @zooby If you do such things so often that designing, implementing and learning a new programming language syntax will be amortized by the milliseconds shaved off in typing `for` loops then you're doing something wrong. Really, you're hunting a ghost.

Comment: @zooby: I'm not sure that a "times 3 times table" is, but outputting a table does not need a loop at all: `%w[a b c].product((1..3).to_a) {|row| puts row.join(', ') }`.

Answer (score 5):

> so you don't want to spend a lot of time typing it out every time for prototyping

If the time it takes you to type a for is an obstacle to your developing ability, then your focus as a developer is massively in the wrong place. **Developers are not typists**, words-per-minute is not in any way a valid metric for development quality.
The more senior a developer becomes, the less time is spent writing code. Development is all about **deciding** to write the right code.

As a simple analogy, JK Rowling's value as a novelist isn't measured by her words per minute or her spelling. It's measured by **what she chooses to write**, which takes thought, planning and decision making. Typing the words is a side activity in comparison.

> The less characters the better

This is patently false. If this were true, you'd be using [CodeGolf.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) as a genuine snippet repository. Good luck with that.

**Readability trumps brevity every single time**. Cutting away essential characters that enhance readability is therefore a bad idea.

All of your syntax suggestions are personal assumptions based on something that makes sense to you. It seems like *you* often use `for` loops, and always use the same structural `for` loop. Okay, that might be the case. But is the language designed for you specifically? What about other developers? Does everyone who often uses a construct need to create their own language that tailors to their needs?

Programming languages, much like all languages, are a **shared information system**. If you split off from the crowd and go speak your own personal language, no one is going to understand you. That doesn't mean you can't be right about what you're saying, but you've lost contact with anyone who didn't think your language was better than the one they already spoke.

Of course different languages exist, just like different programming languages do, but *excessive fragmentation* (= everyone has their own niche language) leads to an inability for large groups of people to communicate. This is exactly why StackExchange uses a single language (English, barring the language SE's and SE's specifically made to be used in a different language) because otherwise we couldn't all communicate with each other.

> so you don't want to spend a lot of time typing it out every time

The beauty of programming is that when a particular usage becomes the predominant use case, we naturally evolve the language to accommodate this predominant usage.

The `for` loop is already such an evolution. It was created after people started realizing that the vast majority of their `while` loops always declared a counter and then just counted up to a max value. So they created the `for` loop to be a clearer indication that this was a counter-based iteration.

Then, they realized that `for` loops most commonly iterate over a full collection (array, list, ...) and the max value was always the collection size (-1 for 0-based-index languages). So they came up with the `foreach` which no longer needs a counter but instead takes in the collection and does the counter/element selection part for you.

Then, they realized that `foreach` loops most commonly were being used for collection transformations, so they created specific methods for these transformations. Based on the language, the names vary (JS has `map()`, `filter()`, `sort()` whereas C# has `Select()`, `Where()`, `OrderBy()`) but most languages that are still actively evolving nowadays have these premade transformation methods.

The point I'm trying to make here is that **languages evolve based on predominant usage by a sufficient amount of people**. Your usage simply isn't in need for optimization because it is not the predominant usage for a sufficient amount of people.

Trying to split it off into a new syntax (a new language even!) brings with it a lot more drawbacks than it does benefits: compiler compatibility issues, syntax differentiation, incompatibilities between languages, libraries that break down or need to be redeveloped for a new language, developers that need to be retrained, invalidated documentation, ...

I think you're not seeing the big picture here. You're looking at your own desk and trying to make global decisions based on what's good for you without considering the issues your decision would create.

> I would like to come up with some ideas for a simpler syntax for a new programming fast prototyping language

Rather than try to reinvent the language, have you considered starting to use an IDE with snippet support?

As a Visual Studio example, consider the following key combination:

```
for [Tab][Tab][Tab] 9 [Return]
```

Which gets you:

[image]

Now you can have the best of both worlds: the ability to quickly write a common construct (all I wrote is `for` and `9` which is even shorter than your suggestions!), but also the necessary verbosity to keep the code readable for the future.

> Maybe another might be in a more python-esque syntax

If you want Pythonesque syntax, maybe start developing in Python?

The benefits of a particular language/syntax often come with drawbacks. Right now, you're only looking at one particular construct and how it benefits you, but you haven't really looked into the impact this may have on your suggested new language.

Your chosen syntax might not make sense for other constructs, or it would lead to a fragmented language where some constructs have a wholly different syntax from others, which is bad.

Comment: You should also mention _redundancy_. If I write "for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)" most random mistakes will not produce valid syntax and bugs are easily found. x 1 5 - what happens if I change a letter? Does it mean something completely different?

Comment: Typing speed is a red herring IMO. The thing about long syntax is that you have to *remember* it, not that you have to *type* it. Hmm, was it `for(int i = 0; i++; i < 100)`? It compiles at least... Or maybe it was `for(int i; i = 0; i = 100)`? The less stuff there is, the harder it is to mess up. `for i = 0 to 99` is a lot harder to mess up, and if you try to write `,` instead of `to` the compiler will say so.

Comment: @user253751: Even if you know the syntax by heart, you'd prefer less keypresses to achieve the same result.